# Name for "all things able to be referenced" by a language

Tags: cross-linguistic

Is there a name for the collection of all things that can be referenced in a language; a language's **universe** perhaps?

For example, the "universe" of English would contain most all things/concepts we humans encounter. The "universe" of a numeral system would contain all quantities.

Is there a proper name for this concept?

Comment: No, not really. Concepts or referents are not that simple to identify, and most categories and limits are imposed by humans, not reality. Where you see a leaf or a branch or a tree or a forest, someone else may see a piece of land or a future farm.

Comment: What can be referenced by a language is probably without limit, as
soon as it includes means to define new concepts. You may want a
slightly different characterization of what you are after. What about
the word "culture".

Comment: In model-theoretic semantics, the 'universe' of entities is referred to as the "domain". This is probably the closest technical term to what you have in mind.